# notation regarding combination of summation of variable

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

Sorry if this is a dumb question. But suppose I have variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ and a vector

$$V=\begin{pmatrix}x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4\\
x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_3x_4\\
x_1x_2+x_1x_4+x_2x_4\\
x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

how can one describe the vector above succinctly, perhaps even symbolically? In words, my best description would be something like:

A vector whose $i$th entry is the sum of all two-element factors from the set $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}\backslash x_1$, or something like

$$V=\sum_{i}^4e_i\left(\sum_{j\neq k\neq i}x_jx_k\right)$$

where $e_i$ is just the standard basis, i.e. $e_1 = (1,0,0,0)^T$
if so, how could one extend it so for if we have a vector concerning $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$, and 4 entries like $x_2x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_5+x_2x_4x_5+x_3x_4x_5$?

Comment: Is it what you are looking for ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: @Lelouch that seems to be it, thank you.